# Java EE Entity doesn't obtain updated database data

Tags: jakarta-ee, javabeans

I'm building an application using Java2EE, and I have several Entities including this two:

Entity Product (Snippet):

```
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products")
    private List<KB> kbs;

    public List<KB> getKbs() {
        return kbs;
    }
}
```

Entity KB ( **K** nowledge **B** ase article) (Snippet):

```
@Entity
public class KB implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Product> products;
}
```

Has you can tell, they are bidirectionally related, so JPA created three tables: Product, KB, and KB_Product.

I also have EJB's and Managed Beans to access the data persisted by this Entities, here's a snippet of the code I use to retrieve the list of associated KB's with a particular Product:

```
@SessionScoped
public class ProductController {
    private List<KB> associatedKBs;

    public List<KB> getAssociatedKBs() {
       this.associatedKBs = current.getKbs();
       return associatedKBs;
    }
}
```

Everything works OK: When I associate a Product to a KB it get's inserted in the database (KB_Product table), but (and here's the problem) the getKBs() method only returns updated data the first time it's called.

**Example:**
1. I create a product named "Computer".
2. I create a new KB article, and associate "Computer" with this KB.
3. This association gets persisted in the KB_PRODUCT table.
4. getKBs() is called by the first time. Everything shows up OK.
5. I create a second KB article, and associate it with "Computer".
6. This association gets persisted in the KB_PRODUCT table.
7. getKBs() is called again but only returns the first association, until I re-deploy the application. After re-deployment, everything shows up.

**Edit:** At first I thought it was a session problem. Turns out that logging out of the application and logging in again doesn't solve the issue, only re-deploying.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've discovered the EntityManager.flush() method, and it did the trick.

References:
http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=26541&tstart=-1